# Same entity relationship using FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create a relationship to the same entity using FluentNHibernate but do not know how. Has anyone succeeded? Can you help me?

This is my entity class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public virtual Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Controller { get; set; }
    public virtual int Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping could be like this

```
public class MenuMap : ClassMap<Menu>
{
  public MenuMap()
  {
      Table("MenuTable");
      Id(x => x.MenuId)
      ...

      // parent
      References(x => x.ParentMenu).Column("ParentId");

      // children, see note below
      HasMany(x => x.ChildMenus)
      .Inverse()
      .KeyColumn("ParentId")
      .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
  }
}
```

NOTE: Because *Menu* instance can have *parent*, it also could have *children*. I extended mapping with a children collection which should be declared like this:

```
public class Menu
{
    ...
    public virtual Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Menu> ChildMenus { get; set; }
}
```